# GLKView, how to blitFrameBuffer, if its possible

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Here is my set up, width and height are GLKView's bounds * scaling

```
private func initFrameBuffer() -> GLuint {
    var framebuffer_id: GLuint = 0
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer_id)
    glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), framebuffer_id)
    return framebuffer_id
}

private func initRenderBuffer(_ width: GLsizei, _ height: GLsizei) -> GLuint {
    var renderBuffer_id: GLuint = 0
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBuffer_id)
    glBindRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), renderBuffer_id)
    glRenderbufferStorage(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RGBA8), width, height)
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), renderBuffer_id)
    return renderBuffer_id
}

func blitz() {
    glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), frameBuffer)
    bindDrawable()
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT), GLenum(GL_LINEAR))
}
```

I am calling `blitz()` in `draw(_ rect)`, and nothing happens, so when I check for error, it gives me a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.

I also tried getting the ios FBO's id and binding it manually in place of calling `bindDrawble()`, this also fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glBlitFramebuffer` copies from the currently bound `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` to the currently bound `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`. Binding to target `GL_FRAMEBUFFER` is an shortcut for binding an FBO to *both* `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` and `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` at the same time, so your blit is from `framebuffer` to `framebuffer`, which is not allowed.